# Are there some methods that can't be mocked by Mockito without the method being called on mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to Mockito, and think it rocks for mocking. I've just come across a case where it doesn't seem like i'm able to get it to work - that being, replacing a method of a normal object with a mock method, ***without*** the method getting called when I try to mock it.

Here's a super simplified example of what I'm trying to do, that sadly, doesn't duplicate the error, but seems to be exactly the same as my real code.

```
public class SimpleTest
{
    public class A
    {
    }

    public class B
    {
      public int getResult(A anObj)
      {
           throw new RuntimeException("big problem");
      }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEz()
    {
      B b = new B();
      B spy = spy(b);

      // Here are both of my attempts at mocking the "getResult" method. Both
      // fail, and throw the exception automatically.

      // Attempt 1: Fails with exception
      //when(spy.getResult((A)anyObject())).thenReturn(10);

      // Attempt 2: In my real code, fails with exception from getResult method
      // when doReturn is called. In this simplified example code, it doesn't ;-(
      doReturn(10).when(spy).getResult(null);
      int r = spy.getResult(null);
      assert(r == 10);
    }
}
```

So currently when I run my test, the test fails by throwing an exception when I try and mock the "getResult" method of the spy. The exception is an exception from my own code (ie a runtime exception), and it happens when I try and mock the "getResult" method = ie when executing the "doReturn" line above.

Note that my real use case is more complex of course... the "B" class has lots of other methods that I want to leave as is, and just mock the one method.

**So my question is how can I mock it so the method isn't called?**

**MAJOR NOTE:** I just rewrote the entire test from scratch and it works fine now. I'm sure I had a bug in their somewhere, but it's not there now - the method isn't called when it's mocked using the spy! and for what it's worth, I'm using the doReturn syntax  in mocking the method.

```
doReturn(10).when(spy).getResult(null);
```

Comment: Hey! The test is way more complex and has lots of domain specific stuff... But the  core of what's failing is those 2 lines the "when...." and "doReturn...." lines... But in your experience, have there ever been any methods you couldn't spy on because the method was throwing an exception when you tried to mock it?

Comment: The line with `when` should definitely throw the exception.  But the line with `doReturn` should work fine.  This is the correct way of doing things.  Are you sure the method isn't `final` or anything like that?  Also, is this the only implementation of `getResult`?

Comment: @BradParks nope, perhaps you should add the stacktrace obtained when it doesn't work. I would also make sure the spy is used in the test (`b` in your question, not `a`)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I updated my pseudocode to be real code, and it works. My mocked method isn't final, but it does have a @Context arg. Heres' the signature: **public Response getResult(@Context HttpServletRequest request)**. Note that I'm passing in null when mocking and calling the method.

Comment: Pseudo code works fine, add real code :) And please stop editing this post, because my answer was for first version :) Radical change requires new question.

Comment: There's too much of a clients code in this to make it testable in any sense here... plus the whole nda thing... But rewriting the pseudocode made me think - just rewrite the entire test from scratch, and i did, and it works fine now. I'm sure I had a bug in their somewhere, but it's not there now - the method isn't called when it's mocked using the spy!

Comment: @DavidWallace: I think your comment was closest to the mark. Can you put it in as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your reedited question works just fine now.**

This commented line is wrong

```
when(spy.getResult((A)anyObject())).thenReturn(10);
```

Should be

```
when(spy.getResult(any(A.class))).thenReturn(10);
```

### Full test (method isn't called)

```
public class SimpleTest {

    public class A {
    }

    public class B {
        public int getResult(A anObj) {
            throw new RuntimeException("big problem");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEz() throws Exception {

        B b = new B();
        B spy = spy(b);

        doReturn(10).when(spy).getResult(null);

        int r = spy.getResult(null);

        assert (r == 10);

    }

}
```

### Result

```
Tests Passed: 1 passed in 0,176 s
```